# (sass):26096 How to fix 'Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after' error in Rails

Tags: css, sass, ruby-on-rails-5.2, precompile

i am run this in local

```
rake assets:precompile --trace RAILS_ENV=production
```

ruby : 2.6.3

rails : 5.2.2

bundler : 2.0.2

puma : 3.12.1

this is my css
`application.css`

```
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, or any plugin's
 * vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any other CSS/SCSS
 * files in this directory. Styles in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
 * It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
*= require font-awesome.css
*= require bootstrap.css
*= require font-awesome.css
*= require lineicons.css
*= require mystyles.css
*= require styles.css
*= require weather-icons.css
```

error log

```
Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "...ather-icons.css": expected "{", was ""
(sass):26096
```

i expect when running `rake assets:precompile --trace RAILS_ENV=production` is successfully

Answer (score 0):

I think you should rename application.css to application.scss  and remove require tree and require self